# Laravel 5.4 Login Weird Encounter

Tags: laravel, laravel-authorization

I have multiple user registered. 
Example: John, Ben and Blake

- First Stack of User registered is John. John can login successfully
  and got his information displayed to the view.
- Next is user Ben, He can login successfully but the information displayed to 
  the view is for John, same with user blake.

I have tried this but no luck:

- php artisan view:clear
- php artisan cache:clear
- php artisan route:clear
- php artisan optimize
- composer dump-autoload

I have check user with this:

> {{ Auth::user()->firstname}}

LoginController

```
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => ['logout', 'userLogout']]);
    }

    public function userLogout()
    {
        Auth::guard('web')->logout();
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

User Model

```
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    't_id','firstname','middlename','lastname','email','password'
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

protected $primaryKey = 't_id';
```

User Form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
{{ csrf_field() }}

<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

        @if ($errors->has('email'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

        @if ($errors->has('password'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            Login
        </button>

        <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
            Forgot Your Password?
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Anyone guys?

Thanks

Comment: Any reason why you don't just use id instead of t_id?

Comment: I am thinking of something about it. Its find with id. Does that affect the login process?